# Angular 5 - add tooltip to string, possibly with Angular Material 2 mat-tooltip

Tags: html, angular, tooltip, angular-material, angular-material2

I would like to dynamically add tooltips to some text. Ideally I would like to do so with the built-in tooltips shipped with [Angular Material 2](https://material.angular.io/), but also a custom solution will do.

As an example, in the sentence `the dog is barking`, I would like to add to the word `dog` a tooltip displaying `german shepherd`.

The text is currently shown like this: `<p>{{ stringFromSecureServer }}</p>`.

So far I've tried with a custom pipe (`addTooltip`) with which I find and replace text:

```
transform(value: string): any {
    value = value.replace('dog', '<span matTooltip="german shepherd">dog</span>');
    value = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(result);
  return value;
}
```

If then I inject in the page the text with `<p [innerHTML]="stringFromSecureServer | addTooltip"></p>`, the text is actually modified, but `matTooltip` ([Angular Material 2 component](https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview)) is converted to `mattooltip` and it won't work.

Assuming that the problem was somehow linket to AM2, I've tried with a custom Directive, based on the excellent [guide by Netanel Basal](https://netbasal.com/create-advanced-components-in-angular-e0655df5dde6).

While the custom `[tooltip]` Directive is working with statically typed DOM elements (e.g. `<span tooltip="test">test</span>`), this still does not work when I find and replace the text as shown above.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

PS
As far as I can tell, I should not have XSS issues because all the strings that I need to work on are NOT user generated. All strings are served by the server through an https connection (Let's Encrypt auto renewed cert)

Comment: You should use a `ComponentFactoryResolver` to dynamically render Angular content, similar to how Angular Material's dialog works.

Comment: @Edric thanks for pointing me to `ComponentFactoryResolver`, it is indeed what I would need to implement this with pure Angular Material 2 components. I'll use it for some other components I'm currently loading with `ngSwitch`. As it adds a bit too overheads for mere tooltips, for this particular problem I'll use [css](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp) only, which I can add with my simple pipe